# ListBox Slide Animation On New Item Added

Tags: wpf, animation, listbox

I am working on a news feed. This will update every so often and if new items are found, I want to slide in the new content from the top.

Right now, I am just having it fade in by doing the following:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding NewsItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">                    
                <Style.Triggers>                                        
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>                                
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>                                      
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />     
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
        ....
</ListBox>
```

This works fine, but I would really like to have the item slide in. I have tried every possible thing I could find and cannot get anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstBox" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding NewsItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY" From="0" Duration="0:0:.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: That did it. I was overlooking adding the setter property. Thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times! So simple and does exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: This is cool. Unfortunately the UnLoad even doesn't work the sameway, to remove the item. I ended up implementing custom panel with Arrange and Measure calls

Comment: Unfortunately this animation occurs also during switching between subpages of my WPF app (after I switch to the subpage which contains a ListView, all ListView alements fires Loaded event and are animated). It is possible to restrict this animation only to the newly added items to the ListView - only first time after the underlying ViewModel of ListItem is constructed?