# WPF ListBox item load step-by-step animation

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

I want to create user control based on ListBox (ListView) with such animation: the items in listbox do not loads all at once, they have to load step-by-step (item-by-item, first then second, then third, etc.) with some timeout between them.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListBox Slide Animation On New Item Added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035766/listbox-slide-animation-on-new-item-added)

Answer (score 0):

The suggested Slide Animation is a view animation.  I think you want a data animation.  Bind to an alternate view only collection.  Populate this collection one at a time from the backing collection with the aid of a timer.  A quick search reveals that a [Dispatch Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559999/how-do-i-create-a-timer-in-wpf) seems to be preferred with WPF usage.