# WPF - How to manipulating labels in an array?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, label

My plan is to create a text feed whereby when a new text line is added, all the current ones animate moving up and the new one is appended to the bottom (animating in an upwards motion and fading in), while the oldest line at the top fades out.

I figured I'm unable to use WinForms for this as there isn't an opacity setting for labels.
So I started a project using WPF.

I have a timer which will be started whenever new text is added, and will animate the fading/moving.

If the next text line only takes up a single line, they all move up by one line, if it takes up 2 lines, they all move up by 2 etc.

Here's a diagram assuming a max display of 3 labels:

```
Label1
Label2
Label3
```

When a new line is added, Label1 gets faded out, the rest animate up (by having their margin.top values changed):

```
Label2
Label3
Label4
```

I know how to create labels like this:

```
labelTest = New Label
labelTest.Content = "Test Line"
labelTest.Margin = New Thickness(-4, 100, 0, 0)
grid.Children.Add(labelTest)
```

But I'll be doing that for every new line, and will need to refer to them individually, I'll also be removing the labels that get faded out, is there a method for disposing them or is that unnecessary?

**Edit:** 
I feel so silly. I could just create an array of labels, but I have a new problem below.
I removed my above timer code and such because I think I typed too much irrelevant to what my question really is and also changed the title.

So I made an array like this:

```
Dim labels() As Label = New Label() {label1, label2, label3} 'etc..
```

And I changed the above label code to this:

```
Dim mrg as Integer = 100
For Each lbl As Label In labels
    mrg -= 10
    lbl = New Label
    lbl.Content = "Text"
    lbl.Margin = New Thickness(-4, mrg, 0, 0)
    grid.Children.Add(lbl)
Next
```

This works great, but how do I manipulate them individually? I tried:

```
labels(0).Content = "New Text"
```

But it doesn't seem to update the text.

Comment: You should look into using WPF's animations to do this, it's what they are made for. Take a look at StoryBoard etc.. 
I have an example that shows a stock ticker. It ticks horizontally, but might be of some use. http://www.jarloo.com/rumormill4/

Comment: Your code to manipulate individual label should work

Comment: can I suggest you to use this instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035766/listbox-slide-animation-on-new-item-added